# difference between Entity Framework and SubSonic , wcf data service

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, subsonic

I am very confused with the use **subsonic** or **ado.net entity framework** or **WCF Data Services** Which one I should choose? 
I creating a middleware (web site) using asp.net mvc.
I seek a compromise between power, speed of implementation, heavy at runtime, abstraction ...
So Which orm i should use?

Comment: Which framework version are you targeting?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Answer (score 0):

All depend on what you really need. In most of tasks ado.net entity framework will be the best one cause:

- It's well known and there are gigabytes of documentation
- It support almost all most popular databases
- Great support
- Pretty fast

Problems:

- It's not to easy to learn all features
- Performance is less instead of small orms
- On our solution we got a lot of problems with implementation of some very specific tasks (like integration with memcached)

My opinion EF is the best in 95% of tasks.

Hope my answer make sense for you